# What can explain this write throughput pattern with an SMR drive?

Tags: hard-drive, rsync

I recently acquired a Seagate Barracuda drive, known to be SMR, to be used as a read-mostly storage.

When populating it with data via rsync I get the following behavior: expected ~50-100MB/s for the first 30GB-100GB or so, then crawling to a near halt of <1MB/s that doesn't resolve itself until the rsync process is terminated and restarted in which case it's immediately back to full write speed again.

While I thought I was aware of the drawbacks of SMR I expected the rewriting to happen in the background and the throughput to oscillate without the need for manual process restarts.

The write load is mostly files 5-50mb in size, Linux 5.4.0 x86_64, all drives involved are local SATA.

Comment: I would say it writes to cache, and that processing the cache happens in the background, but that in your case the data is more than the cache size, so it has to wait for the cache to be processed before it can fill again, which results in throttling.

Comment: But this doesn't explain why I *immediately* get the full wrtite speed after I restart rsync vs *never* getting it without restarting.

Comment: Your "immediately" might be enough time for the cache to be emptied.

Comment: Rsync could literally be pumping the drive as hard as it can and even a brief pause (for a human) could be enough time for the drive to catch up just enough that it seems improved again. The real test would be to have a testing regimen that somehow has fixed delays between killing and restarting rsync and also records how long before the write speed falls down to unacceptable levels again. It is entirely possible that Rsync "waits" for a short while before beginning to write again as it will need to scan everything to work out what has already been done, thus giving the drive more time.

Comment: OR, given that rsync [can be a CPU bound process](https://serverfault.com/questions/613709/should-i-use-rsync-compression-over-a-gigabit-lan) and with rsync generating checksums and so on it could be that what you are seeing is some kind of thermal throttling. I've seen some modern laptops get stuck in one of the PROCHOT modes and essentially kill performance until the temperature drops below a certain point, perhaps some kind of hysteresis in the thermal throttling management. Also see https://lwn.net/Articles/400489/

Comment: You should also check your kernel logs, as sometimes the disk responds too slowly and i/o requests are cancelled by the kernel. see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/541463/119298). If you temporarily disable ext4 journaling it should be faster. You may get better results with the btrfs filesystem, or f2fs (for flash). Using rsync option `--preallocate` may help too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running it in archive mode, no checksums are done and the cpu is mostly idle.
As the drive got over 50% full the "immediate" part no longer holds and it takes some time of disk idling before getting fast write bursts, it still doesn't explain why rsync gets stuck at slow speeds with a mostly empty drive without recovering, my guess is that with the drive getting constant write requests it never gets a chance to do the SMR reorganization and even a short break from them allows it to be accomplished as per @Mokubai